# How to perform search in nested object hierarchy to build list ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I want to build a search function which can result in returning the search response in deeply nested hierarchy.

Type of data I am having::

```
[
  {
    label: "Navigation",
    accordion: true,
    key: "navigation",
    actions: [
      {
        action: "navigateTo",
        label: "Navigate To"
      },
      {
        action: "Back",
        label: "Back"
      },
      {
        action: "closeDialog",
        label: "Close Dialog"
      },
      {
        action: "delay",
        label: "Delay"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

and I am searching "Delay" it will returns the following result.

```
[
  {
    label: "Navigation",
    accordion: true,
    key: "navigation",
    actions: [
      {
        action: "delay",
        label: "Delay"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

If I am searching "navigation" this is expected to return the complete object with a "navigation" label.

```
[
  {
    label: "Navigation",
    accordion: true,
    key: "navigation",
    actions: [
      {
        action: "navigateTo",
        label: "Navigate To"
      },
      {
        action: "Back",
        label: "Back"
      },
      {
        action: "closeDialog",
        label: "Close Dialog"
      },
      {
        action: "delay",
        label: "Delay"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

I need help building a search function which can be able to search the results on the basis of labels in the nested deep hierarchy. Here I want to perform a search on the basis of the "label" field. And will always return the result with its parent-wrapped object.
Here you can check the sample I have created:: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-chihiro-4uv3dz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: So are you expecting only two levels ? labels and actions ?

Comment: Its. hierarchy can grow, means inside action I might have further object and then another with same label field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the search function like this:

```
    function search(data, keyword) {
    // Return the complete data or null if data does not exist in case of our search keyword is empty
    if (keyword && keyword === "") {
        return data ?? null;
    }
    //Return searched result if search keyword is not empty
    let result = data && data.reduce((acc, value) => {
        let item = null;
        if (value["label"].toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            item = value;
        } else {
            if (value["actions"]) {
                let actions = search(value["actions"], keyword); // call recursive function
                item = { ...value, actions };
            }
        }
        //push the item in acc(accumulator) if it is not null
        if (item) {
            acc.push(item);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
    let searchResult = result.filter((item) => {
        return item["actions"]?.length < 1 ? false : true;
    });
    return searchResult;
}
    let result = search(data, "Create");
```

Here is the working example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-tharp-if17ff?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

By the way now the search is case sensitive, you can change the `indexOf` with your desired text camparison.

Comment: It returns an empty array If I'm just searching for "navigation". What I have required is I want the object with its complete children if the label matches with any parent.

Comment: Also, if I am searching for "firestore" it results in nothing but the expected result is I want firestore complete data including its parents etc.

Comment: I updated the logic can you check now

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer id it's solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here i have created this in plain JS. You can modify it according to your taste.

```js
const data = [{
    label: "Navigation",
    accordion: true,
    key: "navigation",
    actions: [{
        action: "navigateTo",
        label: "Navigate To"
      },
      {
        action: "Back",
        label: "Back"
      },
      {
        action: "closeDialog",
        label: "Close Dialog"
      },
      {
        action: "delay",
        label: "Delay"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Backend/Database",
    key: "db",
    accordion: true,
    actions: [{
        label: "Firestore",
        accordion: true,
        key: "fsb",
        actions: [{
            label: "Create document",
            action: "fsCreateDoc"
          },
          {
            label: "Update document",
            action: "fsUpdateDoc"
          },
          {
            label: "Delete document",
            action: "fsDeleteDoc"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "API request",
        action: "api"
      },
      {
        label: "Firebase authentication",
        accordion: true,
        key: "fsbAuth",
        actions: [{
            label: "Firebase login",
            action: "fsbLogin"
          },
          {
            label: "Create account",
            action: "fsbCreateAccount"
          },
          {
            label: "Phone sign-in",
            action: "fsbPhoneLogin"
          },
          {
            label: "Logout",
            action: "fsbLogout"
          },
          {
            label: "Reset password",
            action: "fsbResetPw"
          },
          {
            label: "Verify SMS code",
            action: "fsbVerifySMSCode"
          },
          {
            label: "Send email verification link",
            action: "fsbSendEmailVeriLink"
          },
          {
            label: "Delete user",
            action: "fsbDeleteUser"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const resultContainer = document.querySelector('#result');
let searchWord = "Navigation";

function start() {
  searchWord = document.querySelector('#searchField').value;

  let final = [];
  if (searchWord) {
    for (let elem of data) {
      const res = searchMe(elem);
      if (res) {
        final.push({...res});
      }
    }
  }

  if (final.length) {
    resultContainer.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(final, null, 2) + '</pre>';
  } else {
    resultContainer.innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function searchMe(elem) {
  if (elem.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchWord.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    return elem;
  }

  if (elem.actions && elem.actions.length) {
    const newActions = [];
    for (let action of elem.actions) {
      const res = searchMe(action);
      if (res) {
        newActions.push(res);
      }
    }

    if (newActions.length) {
      return {
        ...elem,
        actions: newActions
      };
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="keyword" id="searchField" onkeyup="start()" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

codesandbox React: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-glitter-njg0mn